# Unable to locate the event handler

Tags: javascript, html

I've [this html source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7aEugGV1GwTeVZDSVdlSmlTbjA/view?usp=sharing) of this url:  `https://login.freecharge.in/login?callbackurl=https://checkout.freecharge.in/payment`. This page has two input fields - login & password.

I want to locate the handler being called when we key-in the login and password. For example when I type these two values then **Sign In** button gets enabled:

```
aaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com
password11233455
```

In the login textfield if I delete last two characters "`om`" by pressing Backspace leaving login to "aaaaaaaaaa@gmail.c" then **Sign In** automatically gets disabled.

### Login field code

The html code of the login field looks like this:

```
<input id="loginEmailMobile" name="loginEmailMobile" autocomplete="loginEmailMobile" type="text" focus-me="vm.focus == 'LOGIN'" focus-delay="200" ng-focus="frmLogin.loginEmailMobile.blured = false" ng-blur="frmLogin.loginEmailMobile.blured = true" required="" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid:true}" ng-model="vm.data.login.emailOrPassword" ng-maxlength="127" ng-pattern="^(([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4})|([6-9][0-9]{9}))$" no-space="" class="ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required ng-invalid ng-invalid-pattern">
```

#### Sign-In Button code

```
<button value="Submit" class="submit disable" ng-class="{'disable':frmLogin.$invalid}" id="signInButton" ng-click="vm.signinClickHandler(frmLogin.$valid)"><span id="textLoginSignIn">SIGN IN</span></button>
```

Now I've searched `loginEmailMobile` in all the files and I don't find this except in this code. So who is listening to this element and taking action? How to find it?

Comment: @nicovank I've already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done via the Angular framework, with the following patter:

```
ng-pattern="^(([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4})|([6-9][0-9]{9}))$"
```

It means if the input does not look like an email, the field is not valid. Then, you didn't post this code, but most likely on the button there's something like `ng-enabled="..."` with a condition that checks if the email field is valid.